# Help with Async task, crashes on .execute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

when my Async task is executed it completely crashes the app
Here is the code to the class. It sits inside of my main activity class.
I'm new to threading, so sorry if I've done something ridiculous lol, I don't fully understand it.

**EDIT:**

```
    private class TeamSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    CharSequence nfo;
    String [] matches;
    protected Void doInBackground(String... teamNumber) 
    {
            //Team information ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //Array of team data
            String [] data = APIconnection.getTeams(teamNumber[0], "");

            //Display basic team info
            nfo = ("\nFormal Team Name:\n" + data[1] + 
                    "\n\nLocation:\n" + data [3] + ", " + data[4] + ", " + data[5] +
                    "\n\nRookie Year:\n" + data[6] +
                    "\n\nRobot Name:\n" + data[7] +
                    "\n\nWebsite:\n" + data[8] + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); 

            //Make match archive --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            String [] events = APIconnection.getEventIdsByYear(year1);
            String [] matches = new String [(events.length*11)];;

            for (int i = 0; i<events.length; i++)
            {
                matches[(i*11) + i] = APIconnection.getMatches2(teamNumber[0], events[i] ,"","")[i];            
            }
            return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...voids ) 
    {}

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        info.setText(nfo);
        matchArchive(matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "stack" you are showing is just a tiny part of the actual exception stack trace. Please show us the full crash so we can help you. You should at least look at the type of exception thrown to see what might be causing it (null pointer? array index out of bounds? etc.)

Comment: @Romain Guy I do have a try catch block that prints the error (Exception e, then it prints e.toString())
but it isn't working, It's just crashing completely

Comment: There must be something in the logs.

Comment: Logcat or another log? (sorry , again, I'm not used to android dev-ing)

Comment: @Nick: My guess is that you are running Eclipse. If so, let Eclipse run past the point of the exception, and a full stack trace will be written to LogCat, available in your DDMS perspective.

Comment: Ok, I've included the logcat log

Comment: Are you sure this logcat excerpt is related to your error? I don't see anything which looks like an exception that could have crashed your app. Independed of this, what do the `clearMatchArchive()` method does? Does it anything UI-related? If you, this may be the cause for your error, because inside of `doInBackground` you aren't allowd to do any UI-related stuff, because `doInBackground` run in a different thread and can't interact with the main UI elements created in the main (UI-)thread. **edit:** Same applies to `matchArchive`

Comment: I don't think it is but they are saying so. (are they? <_<)

Comment: AH that's probably the problem!!! matchArchive(String) and clearMatchArchive(String) Are both UI related! I can move em out, I'll post feedback, thanks!

Comment: You can override `onPostExecute()` method of AsyncTask and execute the methods there safely.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is that a method that is executed after everything? (after all the other methods in the task have executed?)

Comment: Exactly. See my Anwser below ^^

Comment: Thank you :), I'm re-structuring everything now, again. will post feedback.

Comment: It's giving me "The method onPostExecute(Long) from the type SapphireAlliance.TeamSearchTask is never used locally"

Comment: My bad, copy & paste error lol. onPostExecute(Void result) is what you have to use, because your AsyncTask is defined as `extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>`

Comment: Ah, no that wasn't your fault it was a result of my laziness xD, I didn't realize it returned a long.

Answer (score 1):

```
titlets.setText(ttl.toString());
```

Don't touch UI elements in different thread then UI-thread. You can use Activity::runInUiThread(Runnable r) or Handler::post(Runnable r). In second case, handler should be paired with UI-thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class TeamSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    private String[] data;
    protected Void doInBackground(String... teamNumber) {
        // Do your background work! No UI-stuff here!!
        data = APIconnection.getTeams(teamNumber[0], "");

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Do all UI related stuff here, it's executed when the doInBackground is finished
    }
}
```

**edit:** My bad, fixed the error with onPostExecute. You need to use `Void` instead of Long as you use

```
extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
```

which means input parameter is String, Progress parameter type (in onProgressUpdate) and the 3rd one is for the Result.

Comment: Even the other XML data I have to get?

Comment: No, just the Java code of course (the one you did in doInBackground) which is related to your task